# can't install intl in php:7.4-alpine

Tags: php, docker, alpine-linux

I'm just getting started with Docker, and i'm trying to get a ZF2 project running with the php:7.4-alpine image, this is the Dockerfile i currently have

```
FROM php:7.4-alpine

ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/app/public

COPY ./src /var/www/app

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    apache2 \
    php-apache2 \
    zlib-dev \
    icu-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    composer

RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    gd \ 
    intl \
    mysqli \
    pdo_mysql \
    iconv

RUN chmod -R 775 /var/www/app
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/app
RUN cd /var/www/app && composer install

COPY ./apache /etc/apache2

CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-DFOREGROUND"]
```

(I'm using multiple RUN's just to make things quicker while building, I will change it for production)

The problem is, i only get a 500 error, the log shows this

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Locale' not found in /var/www/...
```

From what i googled, this has to do with the intl extension, as you can see, i have it being installed in the Dockerfile, and if i run a php -m in the container's shell, intl is there, but, in a simple ext.php file i setup, with this content:

```php
<?php
    var_dump(get_loaded_extensions());
?>
```

The output is this:

```
array(18) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "Core"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "date"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "libxml"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "pcre"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "zlib"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "filter"
  [6]=>
  string(4) "hash"
  [7]=>
  string(10) "Reflection"
  [8]=>
  string(3) "SPL"
  [9]=>
  string(8) "standard"
  [10]=>
  string(14) "apache2handler"
  [11]=>
  string(4) "curl"
  [12]=>
  string(5) "iconv"
  [13]=>
  string(4) "json"
  [14]=>
  string(8) "mbstring"
  [15]=>
  string(7) "openssl"
  [16]=>
  string(3) "zip"
  [17]=>
  string(4) "Phar"
}
```

As you can see, intl is not here

I had no problems with intl before when I was using mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer, but I was having problems with iconv with it, so I went back to the "vanilla" docker-php-ext-install

I've tried using `docker-php-ext-configure intl` before and `docker-php-ext enable intl` after installing, nothing changed.

Comment: Configure appears to be optional[?], but enable is definitely required.

Comment: @Sammitch i've tried to use `docker-php-ext-enable intl`, nothing changed

Answer (score 7):

So let's start with:

```
$ docker run --rm -it php:7.4-alpine -r 'var_dump($l = new Locale("en_CA"));'

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Locale' not found in Command line code:1
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in Command line code on line 1
```

Yep, that tracks. So then:

```
FROM php:7.4-alpine
RUN apk add icu-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl
RUN docker-php-ext-install intl
RUN docker-php-ext-enable intl
```

and:

```
$ docker build -t php:intl-test ./
```

finally:

```
$ docker run --rm -it php:intl-test -r 'var_dump($l = new Locale("en_CA"));'
object(Locale)#1 (0) {
}
```

So either it's working, or you have a *completely different problem*.

Comment: This. Exactly this.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the output that I got from `docker-php-ext-install intl`:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (icu-uc >= 50.1 icu-io icu-i18n) were not met:

Package 'icu-uc', required by 'virtual:world', not found
Package 'icu-io', required by 'virtual:world', not found
Package 'icu-i18n', required by 'virtual:world', not found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables ICU_CFLAGS
and ICU_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

The simplest solution is just adding `icu-dev` to the installed packages.

Updated to answer original question:
It seems that `docker-php-ext-install` doesn't handle the escaped newlines well.  I don't have time at the moment to look into why this is.  Putting all extensions on one line should work.

If you're interested in my debugging process for these types of problems, I run something like `docker run --rm -ti --entrypoint sh php:7.4-alpine` and just run the commands directly.

Comment: I've updated to hopefully answer your question properly.

Comment: nope, this did not solve it, i managed to "fix" the intl part by adding php-intl in the apk add command, but then i started getting problems related to PDO, there's definitely some serious problems with my `docker-php-ext-install`, and it's not the escaped newlines thing

Comment: I don't know - commenting out the operations on files and folders that I don't have, the image builds find and intl is there.  Is it possible your composer.json is causing a problem?

Answer (score 3):

Thank you @Ovinz

Just adding to my Dockerfile

```
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-data-full
```

And everything goes well (twig intl in my case)

Answer (score 3):

In my case none of the solutions proposed by the kind colleagues worked, I share the solution that solved the problem, I found it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243645/how-can-i-install-development-libraries-for-icu-le-and-icu-uc)

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Install dependencies

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    libzip-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    mysql-common \
    libldap2-dev \
    libicu-dev

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl \
&& docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli \
&& docker-php-ext-install gd \
&& docker-php-ext-enable gd \
&& docker-php-ext-configure ldap \
&&  docker-php-ext-install ldap \
&& docker-php-ext-configure intl \
&& docker-php-ext-install intl \
&& docker-php-ext-enable intl
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I use `FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine` and to make it works fully, I had to add this lib as well
`icu-data-full`

For instance
`RUN apk add icu-data-full`

Without this I had the extension but not languages or no translated context for dates for instance (Symfony & Twig)

Answer (score 1):

Applicable to PHP 7.4 and 8+:

You have to install `icu` packages. Add to Dockerfile:

```
RUN apk add icu-dev
```

This will also install `icu-libs` and `icu-data-full` as dependencies, you don't have to specify them explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

https://releasecandidate.dev/posts/2020/how-to-install-php-ext-intl-on-alpine-docker/

```
RUN set -xe \
    && apk add --update \
        icu \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .php-deps \
        make \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        $PHPIZE_DEPS \
        zlib-dev \
        icu-dev \
        g++ \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        intl \
    && docker-php-ext-enable intl \
    && { find /usr/local/lib -type f -print0 | xargs -0r strip --strip-all -p 2>/dev/null || true; } \
    && apk del .build-deps \
    && rm -rf /tmp/* /usr/local/lib/php/doc/* /var/cache/apk/*
```